# iPhone in App purchases subscription expire issue

Tags: iphone, subscription

I implemented inApp purchases with a subscription and when the user buys it in sand box and the subscription expires after lets say 5 minutes the system says "Product already purchased. Do you want to renew it ?" when the user tries to buy it again.

How can I tell the apple server that the subscription has expired ?? And that the user really needs to BUY(!) it again in order to use certain features in the app ?

I set the subscription time to 5 minutes for app testing of course....

There is another user with exactly the same problem but people did not understand his problem :) [iPhone In App purchase subscriptions auto renew?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078425/363691).

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to say when the subscription expires. you have to watch that on your server and application has to ask the user to renew the subscription.

there's also no way to check whether current device has active subscriptions other than log it on your server and ask your server each time.

everything with these subscriptions is just frustrating.